# How to generate Dynamic Template field in Asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I am new for this so that asking these questions..

How can I generate a Dynamic Template field in Asp.net with C#?

Comment: Are you looking for this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13462/How-to-create-template-columns-dynamically-in-a-gr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DynamicallyTemplatedGridViewHandler` implementing `ITemplate`  interface.....For details, have a look [here](http://aspalliance.com/1125_Dynamically_Templated_GridView_with_Edit_Delete_and_Insert_Options.all)